# Need help with a MySQL query

Tags: mysql, authentication

My query needs to do this

- get user details
- get last login out of a table of logins that are logged
- get number of failed logins, but *only* from the last 3 logins of that user

My problem seems to be in the subquery. I want the `WHERE` part of that to reference the user_id that was matched earlier in the outer query. Is that even possible? Have I made a huge mess of this query?

```
$query = 'SELECT users.id, 
                         users.email, 
                         users.password, 
                         users.first_name, 
                         users.last_name,
                         max(user_logins.datetime) as last_login,
                         count(user_logins.failed) as failed_logins,

            FROM users, user_logins
            WHERE users.email = ' . Database::instance()->escape($email) . '
                AND users.id = user_logins.user_id
                AND user_logins.datetime IN (SELECT datetime FROM user_logins WHERE user_id = users.id  )
            LIMIT 1';
```

The `last_login` seems to be working great. The reason I want the last 3 is so that I can check if the last 3 are failed, then set a timeout for this user to log in.

I can not go back and do an `UPDATE users SET failed = 1 WHERE failed = 0` because then I won't have an accurate log of user logins. I'd like to see any that fail.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try the following. It should give you the three latest logins in a sub-query, `SUM` up the number of failed logins and get the time of the last login.

`MySQL` allows not to list every column selected in the `GROUP BY`, with other databases you would have to add all columns of `users` that you need to the `GROUP BY`.

```
$query = '
SELECT u.id, 
       u.email, 
       u.password, 
       u.first_name, 
       u.last_name,
       MAX( ul.datetime ) as last_login,
       SUM( ul.failed ) as failed_logins,
FROM users u
JOIN ( SELECT user_id, datetime, failed
       FROM user_logins
       ORDER BY datetime DESC
       LIMIT 3 ) ul
  ON ( u.id = ul.user_id )
WHERE u.email = ' . Database::instance()->escape($email) . '
GROUP BY u.id
';
```